# Eliminate or Reduce Potential Conflicts in a Frequently Touched Code

Tags: swift, git, logic

Imagine having a big team maintaining a monolithic repo. Team members follow git-flow which means that at any point of time, you have ~10 or more actively developed feature branches. Now imagine that the codebase relies heavily on a static array to represent features, and almost every single feature branch will add to the same array. Something like this:

*(note that the code is written in Swift, since I'm very familiar with it, but it can be treated more as a concept, unless you have a solution that leverages something specific to Swift)*

```
struct Features {
    
    struct Feature {
        let id: String
        let title: String
        let isOn: Bool
    }
    
    static var all: [Feature] {
        .init(id: "a-cool-feature", title: "A Cool Feature", isOn: false),
        .init(id: "a-cooler-feature", title: "A Cooler Feature", isOn: false),
        .init(id: "the-coolest-feature", title: "The Coolest Ever Feature", isOn: true),
    }

}
```

Now the problem is, continuously having conflicts is almost inevitable. Say that 2 branches were adding new features in parallel, now Branch B is pulling from the base branch where Branch A was just merged, and now you have a conflict:

```
struct Features {
    
    struct Feature {
        let id: String
        let title: String
        let isOn: Bool
    }
    
    static var all: [Feature] {
        .init(id: "a-cool-feature", title: "A Cool Feature", isOn: false),
        .init(id: "a-cooler-feature", title: "A Cooler Feature", isOn: false),
        .init(id: "the-coolest-feature", title: "The Coolest Ever Feature", isOn: true),
<<<<<<< HEAD
        .init(id: "way-cooler-than-the-coolest", title: "Way Cooler Than The Coolest Feature Ever", isOn: true),
=======
        .init(id: "no-one-understands-me", title: "Why god why why?", isOn: true),
>>>>>>> b3bc030 (FeatureA)
    }

}
```

Clearly, these conflicts impact everyone's productivity and prevent our automations from continue working smoothly until a human solves the conflicts manually. Hence, I'm looking for inspirations and/or clever ideas or even tweaks to the formatting of the file where we can potentially reduce or totally eliminate these conflicts.

I understand that we can completely refactor the codebase in a more composable way, where different features don't have to touch the same areas all the time, but I was hoping that we can avoid big changes at the time being.

Things I've done so far:

1. Originally, an enum with different cases was used. Because Swift treats enums almost like structs / classes, we could add the cases plus calculated variables to return the proper values based on the current case. Even though that was elegant, it was leading to more conflicts, since the cases plus the implementation of every variable will all introduce conflicts. Things are significantly better now, but still conflicting.

Things I've thought of:

1. This is properly stupid, but I was thinking of somehow sorting all the values in the array alphabetically every time anyone adds to the array. This could be manual for now. The hope is, it will be less likely that multiple features will be adjacent that git will be confused. It won't totally eliminate the conflicts though. It could also lead to even more conflicts in case someone forgot to sort them initially (assuming it'll be manual for now.)

Any thoughts? Even big refactor ideas are welcome. I might not fully implement them right away, but I might get inspired at least. :)

Comment: The easy ones that come to mind? Sorting the features? Allowing developers to add features at places other than the last one? That won't _eliminate_ the risk of conflict.... but should reduce it a lot.

Comment: @eftshift0 Thanks! Can you think of a way to reliably automate the sorting?

Comment: Other than teaching your developers about the alphabet? :-D

Comment: Oh.... you mean, to automate it so that it is _sorted_ in a single shot so that then you ask your developers to add them in a sorted fashion from now on? I have no idea.... **forcibly** _volunteer_ someone to do it.

Comment: @eftshift0 Sorting them initially is straightforward. I meant automating the sorting instead of relying on people manually do it, who can easily forget, etc. I can think of a pre-commit hook with a shell script maybe. I was wondering if there are simpler and more seamless solutions though.

Comment: What about generate the array from several files owned by domain or team ?

Comment: If you go with the sorting idea (which IMHO is a decent idea with minimal impact), I'd probably lean towards sorting it initially, and asking devs to continue with the sorting themselves. I wouldn't recommend automating the sort afterwards because that may necessitate the automation of new commits, which brings in some new annoyances along with it. Since the general purpose of the sort is to spread out insertions, it doesn't actually matter if Devs get the sorting perfect, as long as it's better than always inserting at the end.

Comment: @TTT Agree. I guess I'll go with that for now. Thanks for the input!